# Java. Не выполняется условие цикла While

Tags: java, циклы, while

Мне понадобилось забить в массив ряд Фибоначчи до определённого значения, я попытался сделать это таким образом:

```
int[] arr = new int[40];
arr[0] = 1;
arr[1] = 2;
arr[2] = 3;
int i = 2;
while (arr[i] < 4000000) {
    arr[i] = arr[i - 1] + arr[i - 2];
    System.out.println(arr[i]);
    i++;
}
```

При запуске условие цикла `while` не работает и массив забивается полностью, не останавливаясь на 4х миллионах, если добавляю в цикл:

```
if (arr[i] > 4000000) break;
```

То это помогает.

Почему не работает условие в цикле?

Comment: `почему не работает условие в цикле` Потому что вы сначала проверяете arr[i], а только потом записываете туда значение?

Answer (score 2):

Проблема решена, я невнимателен и ошибся в условии.

```
int[] arr = new int[40];
arr[0] = 1;
arr[1] = 2;
int x = 0;
for (int i = 2; arr[i-1] < 4000000; i++) 
    arr[i] = arr[i-1] + arr[i-2];
```